# What is bob container and checkpoint

Tags: azure-eventhub

I have just started learning azure event hub and is following this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-send), but there are things which I don't quit understand after reading through the documentation.

The article has the following passage and my question is

- it said about a "bob container", what is it about and is it necessary to have a "bob container" for using event hub?
- what is checking pointing and partition, and is it necessary to have it for using event hub ?

> In this quickstart, you use Azure Storage (specifically, Blob Storage)
> as the checkpoint store. Checkpointing is a process by which an event
> processor marks or commits the position of the last successfully
> processed event within a partition. Marking a checkpoint is typically
> done within the function that processes the events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get familiar with the basic concepts and terminology for Event Hubs, I'd recommend starting with the docs on [Event Hubs Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features), which will guide you through things like namespaces, Event Hub instances, and partitions while explaining how they relate to one another.

With respect to your questions around checkpointing and storage:

- Checkpointing is a process by which a consumer tracks its position in the event stream for an Event Hub partition, effectively marking which events have been processed. When a consumer connects, it will need to specify where to start reading events.  Persisted checkpoint data is typically used when requesting the position to ensure that it begins reading from the spot where a previous consumer left off rather than reprocessing events that have already been seen.
- The default storage provider for the event processors in the Event Hubs client library make use of Azure Blob storage in order to persist checkpoints as well as coordinate with other processors to share processing work between them.

Since you're just starting to explore Event Hubs, you may find it easier to work through the [samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/eventhubs/azure-messaging-eventhubs/src/samples) from the Event Hubs client library.  They take a bit narrower view than the quick start guide and will introduce concepts in smaller chunks.